# Slow access to Tomcat web application from another PC

Tags: performance, tomcat, response

The access to my web application running Windows 2008 Server on localhost is fast; however, when I tried to access the web application through another PC (exp: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/appname) is takes about one minute to load a simple login page. Any input regarding this matter is much appreciated.

Further information, the firewall is already off and the setup within a LAN environment without Internet access.

Answer (score 1):

With this little information it is almost impossible to debug your situation.  However, I'll take a guess based on what you've provided.

If you're running on an internal LAN, the problem is likely that you don't have reverse DNS configured for your server.  Your server has some made-up name for which only forward-DNS exists.  When Tomcat receives a request it tries to look up the hostname based on the IP address, and this can take a long time to time-out.

Comment: My bad, I shouldn't have put "webserveripadd" as it's confusing. Currently, I'm accessing the web server with ip address.

Comment: Answer still stands.  Do you have reverse DNS for the server IP address?  On Windows use `nslookup`, on Linux use `dig -x`.  If not, try creating an entry in /etc/hosts for the server's IP address (on the server).